# Integrate Azure B2C in Swift with Native Login Screen

Tags: ios, swift, azure, azure-ad-b2c

We are building an iOS app in which we will have users sign up and login with emails and passwords. I am trying to use Azure AD B2C to handle authenticating a user via email and password fields from our login screen. We're trying to keep the screens all native without having to open up a new web view, but all examples I'm finding in [documentation](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-ios-swift-native-msal) and in various YouTube [discussions](https://youtu.be/h5bxhZRF4mI?t=519) looks like they still open up a web view, albeit customized.

Is there a way to simply initiate the claims based authentication without having to use the separate web view?

Answer (score 0):

If it is just Authentication then you can use Resource Owner Password Credential Flow. See [B2C Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc). However this would not work for SignUp.

Comment: Thansk Phil, but I have been reading that ROPC is not recommended as it's a grant type that is not considered to be the most secure. Instead, I've been seeing that for native apps, an OAuth Authorization Flow with PKCE is recommended. Is there a way to perform the Auth Flow with PKCE without redirecting to a Safari view?

Comment: I do not believe PKCE is supported with B2C. However even with this you will still need to execute an Authorization code grant flow which will redirect the user to the Safari view. If you need native authentication then you will need to use ROPC, however as you have already stated this is less secure than redirecting the user to a Safari view.

Comment: I think you're right that even with PKCE it still requires a web view redirect. But just for reference, according to some AADB2C posts, it looks like PKCE is supported - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-ad-b2c-google-signin-issue/. I think as long as AppAuth supports it, I think B2C can as well.